# Viewport - Can't find in plugin/theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, meta-tags

I'm trying to disable the view port for this website [Tux Builder Website](http://ihateyousohere.com/bewbs/5587ba3d53820/1205/) and am unable to find it. This is a woo commerce plugin with the theme omega. When I inspect the source code I can see that it's there but can not find it in the header/functions/index php. I've also searched the plugin php files and can't find any meta references to the theme.

Can someone please point me in the correct direction. I've been working on this for about an hour now. I finally finished the CSS edits and this is the last thing alluding me.

Comment: I narrowed the meta tags down to being hooked with wp_head. I'm trying to find the view port meta tag in this array of files in "wp-includes". Any further direction would be most appreciated!

Comment: header.php in the theme most likely